# Restrict radio buttons selection in two columns of repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, radio-button

In first column I am displaying list of colleges. Each college has multiple courses which has been displayed in second column.

**Restriction to be imposed on user selection:**

When user selects a college (say MIT), He should be allowed to select courses corresponding to selected college only (computer science & mechanical engg in this case).

How can I achieve this functionality using jQuery ?

I am binding following data into nested repeater.

```
    public string currentCollege { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> colleges;
    class College
    {
        public College(string s)
        {
            Course = s;
        }
        public string Course { get; set; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colleges = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        colleges.Add("mit", new List<string>(new string[] { "computer science", "mechanical engg." }));
        colleges.Add("caltech", new List<string>(new string[] { "electrical engg", "cryptography"}));
        colleges.Add("harvard", new List<string>(new string[] { "language", "arts", "science" }));
        rptColleges.DataSource = colleges;
        rptColleges.DataBind();
    }
    protected void rptColleges_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptCourseNow = (e.Item.FindControl("rptCourses") as Repeater);
            rptCourseNow.DataSource = colleges[currentCollege];
            rptCourseNow.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

the markup is as follows -

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptColleges" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptColleges_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbCollege" runat="server" value=<%# DataBinder.Eval((KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>)Container.DataItem, "Key") %> />
                <%# currentCollege = (string)DataBinder.Eval((KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>)Container.DataItem, "Key") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptCourses" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbCourse" value="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
                            &nbsp; <%#Container.DataItem %>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please tell us what your application is trying to accomplish. We are not your colleagues that know what you are trying to do. Right now you question sounds kinda vague.

Comment: @xiaomao I could have been more explicit about that. Does update question makes it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to group radio buttons to one college. You can use the GroupName property of the RadioButton to make sections of radio buttons to be mutually exclusive.

Check out this link:

[RadioButton.GroupName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx)